# Australia - Subpoena bank records

Tags: contract-law, court, subpoena

I'm self-representing for a case that is centred on whether an amount of money was raised or not. I have reason to believe the defendant is likely to alter any documents he presents related to bank transactions to demonstrate that such an amount was raised. Is it possible to subpoena the bank records of that account directly from the bank for a small-claims case in NSW?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Good luck doing this without legal training or representation.

Comment: What would I need to look-up/research to get a better understanding of the specific process for submitting a subpoena to a bank?

Comment: www.courts.justice.nsw.gov.au